# Assign the result of a command to a variable (batch file)

Tags: batch-file

I want to store the result of a command in a variable in a for loop in a batch script. I want to loop through a series of .sql files, count how many lines each file consists of and sum up the line counts.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set /a count=0
set /a t=0

for /f %%a in ('dir /b *.sql') do (
    @echo %%a <- THIS PRINTS THE FILE NAME
    @set t=findstr /r /n "^" %%a | find /C ":" <- THIS IS INCORRECT
    echo %t% <- I WANT TO PRINT THE LINE COUNT FOR THE FILE
    @set /a count+=%t% <- INCREASE THE COUNTER
)
echo %count% <- PRINT TOTAL LINE COUNT
```

When I run

```
findstr /r /n "^" *.sql | find /C ":"
```

in a command window it works, and I know I could use that for the end objective, but this question is about the variable assignment.
Where is my mistake? The variable `t` is assigned the value 0 all the time.

**UPDATE**: (Still not working)

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set /a count=0
set /a t=0

for /f %%a in ('dir /b *.sql') do (
    @echo %%a
    for /L %%b in ('findstr /r /n "^" %%a ^| find /C ":"') do (
        set /a count+=%%b
    )
)
echo !count!
```

For anyone interested reading this later, here is the final (working version):

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET /a count=0
SET /a t=0

for /f %%a in ('dir /b *.sql') do (
    @echo %%a
    for /f %%b in ('findstr /r /n "^" %%a ^| find /C ":"') do (
        set t=%%b
    )
    ECHO !t!
    @SET /a count+=!t!
)
ECHO "Total:" !count!
```

Comment: you Need [delayed expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

Comment: I have `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` at the top

Comment: that only enables delayed expansion. You need to use it. Reference your variable with `!t!` inside the block.

Comment: `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` is useles when you are doing `echo %count%`. You have to do `echo !count!` instead.

Comment: @MichaelS `%count%` is ok. It's outside the block. The Problem is with `echo %t%`

Comment: I have changed to `echo !t!`, it still shows 0 though. I think the problem is the line `@set t=findstr /r /n "^" %%a | find /C ":"` ? Do I need to do `@set !t!=....` ?

Comment: well, that's the Syntax for far more modern programming languages. In `cmd` you can't use objects. Use a `for` instead (like you did with `dir /b *.SQL`)

Comment: @Stephan I´m sorry I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: The only way you can assign the result of a command to a variable is using the FOR command.  Just like you are doing with the DIR command.

Comment: @Stephan See my update, it's not working, it gets stuck at the inner loop.

Comment: it's `/f`, not `/L`...

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!

Comment: just a note: `set /a` has an advanced syntax: you can use variables without `%` or `!`: `set /a count+=t` works fine (even in delayed expansion context).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@set t=findstr /r /n "^" %%a | find /C ":" <- THIS IS INCORRECT
```

doesn't work. It sets the variable `t` to the string `findstr /r /n "^" %%a` and filters the Output of the `set` command (which Outputs nothing) with `| find /C ":"`, which Counts exactly Zero colons in nothing.

The best way of doing it, is:

```
for /f %%x in ('findstr /r /n "^" %%a ^| find /C ":"') do set t=%%x
```

**Edit** I was so focussed on repairing your code, that I didn't really realize, that you just want to count all lines of all *.SQL files. That's quite easy. No need for delayed expansion:

```
set count=0
for /f %%a in ('type *.sql  2^>nul ^| find /n /v ""') do set /a count+=1
echo %count%
```

`2>nul` prevents `type` to print the file names to the screen.

**Edit2**
my solution with 203 files, 47763 lines in total needs about 24 seconds. Aschipfl's `edit2` solution about seven **milli**seconds. Impressive... `find /c` must have a really efficient method to count the lines.

My slightly changed code to use this capability:

```
set count=0
for /f %%a in ('type *.sql  2^>nul ^| find /c /n /v ""') do set /a count+=%%a
echo %count%
```

which also needs about 7ms. No big surprise, as it's basically the same code as Aschipfl's - just formatted differently.

Comment: @jensa: found a shorter solution that may fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use `findstr /N /R "^"` to precede each line with line number and `:` and count the number of lines containing `:` afterwards.

To count the number of lines a text file contains, you only need to redirect it into `find /C /V ""`, like this:

```
< "\path\to\file.txt" find /C /V ""
```

To use this within your `for` loop, you could do this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set /A COUNT=0
set /A T=0

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%A in ('dir /B "*.sql"') do (
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    echo(%%~A
    for /F %%B in ('^< "%%~A" find /C /V ""') do (
        endlocal
        set /A T=%%B
    )
    echo(!T!
    set /A COUNT+=T
)
echo Total: %COUNT%

endlocal
exit /B
```

The toggling of delayed expansion is done to avoid trouble with exclamation marks `!` in any of the `*.sql` file names, which would be ignored otherwise and the error message `The system cannot find the file specified.` would appear. Delayed expansion is only required because of the (debug) line `echo(!T!`; if you remove that, you can disable delayed expansion for the entire script.

---

#### Edit #1:

Here is a compacted variant of the above script, without any temporary variable `T` and with delayed expansion disabled:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set /A COUNT=0

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%A in ('dir /B "*.sql"') do (
    for /F %%B in ('^< "%%~A" find /C /V ""') do (
        echo(%%~A:  %%B
        set /A COUNT+=%%B
    )
)
echo TOTAL:  %COUNT%

endlocal
exit /B
```

And here is a script that uses a single `for /F` loop to retrieve the number of lines, which lets `find` search for the `*.sql` files like `find /C /V "" "*.sql"`, then takes its output that looks like `---------- file.sql: 5` for instance, splits off the count after `:` and sums up all of them. This approach needs delayed expansion again:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set /A COUNT=0

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%A in ('find /C /V "" "*.sql"') do (
    set "LINE=%%~A"
    echo(%%~A
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set /A T=!LINE:*: =!
    for /F "delims=" %%B in ("!T!") do (endlocal & set /A COUNT+=%%B)
)
echo TOTAL:  %COUNT%

endlocal
exit /B
```

Yes, there is a second `for /F` loop nested as well, but this is required for transferring the value of `T` over the `endlocal` barrier.

---

#### Edit #2:

Here is probably the best solution for determining the total number of lines over multiple files. This lets `type` output every line of all the `*.sql` files, which are then counted by `find`. Therefore the `for /F` loop iterates once only, so the overall performance of this script is quite great:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set /A COUNT=0

for /F "delims=" %%A in ('
    2^>nul type "*.sql" ^| find /C /V ""
') do (
    set /A COUNT+=%%A
)
echo TOTAL:  %COUNT%

endlocal
exit /B
```